# ubuntu make file question

Tags: make, makefile

I have a little question on a make file, here is the code:

```
KERNEL_VERSION := $(shell uname -r)
KERNEL_MODLIB  := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)
KERNEL_SOURCES := $(shell test -d $(KERNEL_MODLIB)/source && echo $(KERNEL_MODLIB)/source || echo $(KERNEL_MODLIB)/build)
CPPFLAGS       += -DDRIVER_ERROR -DDRIVER_DEBUG
obj-m   := main.o
KDIR    := $(KERNEL_SOURCES)
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
     $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules 
clean:
     $(RM) main.ko.unsigned  main.mod.c  main.mod.o  main.o modules.order  module.symvers .main* .tmp_versions/*
```

I want to know what does this code do:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

thx for advance~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command changes to the directory `$(KDIR)` and runs make from there to build the target `modules`.

`$(MAKE)` is a macro which runs the make executable. The reason for it (instead of just using `make`) is that that executable could have different names.

`-C <directory>` changes to a certain directory before running make.

`SUBDIRS=<variable>` defines the variable `SUBDIRS` when running make.

`modules` means it will try to build that target.

Comment: thx, but where will it put the target "module" built, in the $(KDIR) or in SUBDIRS?

Comment: It depends on that makefile - "modules" might not actually be a filename.

Comment: indeed i found KBUILD_EXTMOD ?= $(SUBDIRS) and the definition of modules in the $KDIR makefile. Thx for the quick answer~